# Button function not working (does not change slide in animated presentation)

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I'm making an animated presentation of diffusion in Tkinter, but my button doesn't seem to be doing its command when I press it.

i've tried using 'command' and defining the command before the line with making the button, but it doesn't respond (doesn't add 1 to the 'slide' variable). Here is my minimal reproducible example:

```py
from tkinter import *
import random
import time
tk = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(tk, width = 400, height = 400)
tk.title('Diffusion')
canvas.pack()

#CHANGE SLIDES
slide = 1
def changeSlide():
    slide += 1

#MAKES BUTTON FOR NEXT SLIDE
nexT = Button(tk, text = 'NEXT', command = changeSlide)
nexT.pack()

if slide == 2:
    #DRAW PARTICLES   
    particle = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 20, 20, fill = 'orange')
```

I expect the slide to change to the animation, but what I get instead is a nearly blank window, apart from the button itself.

Comment: First of all, the `slide` in `changeSlide()` is a local variable, unrelated to the global `slide`.  Adding a `global` declaration would fix that, but the button still wouldn't do anything, because nothing is looking at the value of the variable.  Your `slide == 2` test was executed *once*, as the program started up, and the variable had the value of 1 at that time.  Basically, you need to do everything that should happen in response to a button click from inside the Button's `command=` handler.

Comment: @jasonharper OK, thanks! Will try.

Comment: @jasonharper ‘everything’ as in?